# How should I *intentionally* stop a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a migration to run, but before it runs I want to verify certain conditions (i.e. the migration calls an instance method on a model, and I want to ensure that the method exists before running the migration).

With that in mind, I can't find any documentation explaining how to stop the migration if the verification doesn't pass. It seems most likely that raising an exception is the smart way to do this. I found `ActiveRecord::Rollback` which looks like a good candidate, because it explicitly rolls back a transaction, but it also has the characteristic of not re-raising once the transaction is rolled back, so I probably won't see any messages I attach to the exception.

I've been searching things like "rails cancel migration" but all the results seem to deal with migrations which have been unintentionally canceled. I want to fail intentionally (and gracefully) in certain conditions instead.

Comment: Interesting question. FWIW I also thought of manually raising an exception too. Can't make any claims about whether its the best approach, but it will certainly work. The side effect of course is the migration will not be considered successful, and will attempt to run again next time you `rake db:migrate` (which is your intention, I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was actually `raise Exception`, because `ActiveRecord::Rollback` would count the migration as completed and not allow for it to be re-run after fixing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you raise an exception inside of a migration, it will stop the migration.

Depending on what you need you could also try creating an interactive migration:

```
puts "*** What would you like to do? ***"
puts "(a)dd columns AND copy data"
puts "(c)olumns only (no data copying)"
puts "(d)ata only (no column adding)"
puts "(q)uit"
reply = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

Or just putting a `if` confidition inside your migration and only running the commands based on a state. The migration will still complete but the operations will not run.

Comment: Interactive would work if the interaction was only triggered when the condition failed ("It broke. What do you want to do?"). Might also be tough to run in production (i.e. on a remote host). I'd like to *avoid* having the migration complete if the operations don't run, because I'd want to go back and re-run after fixing the problem. (That would be effective if I didn't want to re-run, though.)